# Tricky query solution

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Does anyone have any idea on how can you create a product filtering query (or queries) that will emulate the results on this page?

http://www.emag.ro/notebook_laptop

**Explanation**

If you press HP as a brand, the page will show you all the HP products, and the rest of the available filters are gathered from this query result. Fine and dandy until now, I got this licked w/o any problems.

Press 4GB Ram, and ofcourse you will see all HP products that have this property/feature. Again fine and dandy, got no problems until here.

BUT if you look closely you will see that the Brand features now show also, let's say Acer, having a few products with the 4GB feature, and maybe more after Acer, and the checkbox isn't yet pressed.

The only ideea that comes to mind is to make that much more queries to the database to get these other possibilities results.

After you start checking the 3rd possible option (let's say Display size) the things start to complicate even more.

I guess my question is:
Does anyone has any idea on how to make this w/o taxing the server with tons of queries ?

Thank you very much for reading this far, I hope I made myself clear in all this little story.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really "tons" of queries, it's one query per attribute type (brand, RAM, HDD). Let's say you have selected HP, 4GB RAM and 250GB disk. Now for each attribute type select products according to the filter, *except* for the current type, and group by results by the current type. In a simplistic model, the queries could look like this:

```
SELECT brand, count(*) FROM products WHERE ram='4BG' AND disk='250GB' GROUP BY brand
SELECT ram, count(*) FROM products WHERE brand='HP' AND disk='250GB' GROUP BY ram
SELECT disk, count(*) FROM products WHERE brand='HP' AND ram='4BG' GROUP BY disk
SELECT cpu, count(*) FROM products WHERE brand='HP' AND ram='4BG' AND disk='250BG' GROUP BY cpu
...
```

You should have indexes on the columns, that every query doesn't do a sequential scan over the table. Of course there are some "popular" combinations and you will likely have to display the same numbers on multiple pages when the user is sorting/navigating the list, so you might want to cache the numbers and invalidate the cache on update/insert/delete.

Comment: I think this may work ... I going to try and and come back with the results :)

Thanks a lot man!

Comment: Use COUNT(1) instead of COUNT(*). It's faster because it doesn't have to go through all the columns and see if they are NULL.

Comment: @Felix: That's incorrect, `count(*)` does exactly the same as `count(1)` - it counts rows. It will check if they are `NULL` only if you use `count(column)`.

Comment: It worked! Didn't had too much time to develop it, and I managed to get it done over the weekend, but the main idea is that it's perfect! Thank you Lukas!! http://technica.cytest.info/cyprus/laptop-computers to see it in action...

Comment: No problem, glad it worked for you. Now you have some broken non-laptop pages on the site, but I guess you know about it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at sql

```
UNION
```

syntax.

"[UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) is used to combine the result from multiple SELECT  statements into a single result set."

Comment: Thanks for the idea :) Never used UNION but it looks like it might help in some cases!

Answer (score 0):

It could be that there is some sophisticated means of determining some computed distance of a result from your criteria, but maybe it is as simple as using an OR in the query rather than an AND.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention I have used OR between the filters in the same group, and AND between the groups.